# How to open existing Windows Phone 8 project solution with Windows Phone SDK 7.8?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sdk

I'm stuck with an issue. I've an existing Windows Phone 8.0 project created with Windows Phone SDK 8.0, but I need to emulate that in a different environment (at my school's computer) which is running **Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit**.

So the Question is:

Is it possible to open/compile/emulate my existing project with **Windows Phone SDK 7.8** if I have that IDE on the Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit OS?

I'm new here. Every answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot open WP 8.0 project with WP7.8 SDK